# Prove that this $1$-differential form on $S^1$ is well-defined

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, spheres

Let $U_i:=\{p\in S^1:x_i\ne 0\}$, $i=1,2$, be two open sets of $S^1$. Define
$$
\omega_p :=
\begin{cases}
\Bigl(\bigl(-\frac{dx_2}{x_1}\bigr)|_{U_1}\Bigr)_p\,\,\,\;\text{if}\,\,p\in U_1\\
\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{dx_1}{x_2}\bigr)|_{U_2}\Bigr)_p\,\,\,\;\text{if}\,\,p\in U_2\\
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove that this is a well-defined $1$-form on $S^1$.

What I have to do is to show that for $p\in U_1\cap U_2$,
$$
\Bigl(\bigl(-\frac{dx_2}{x_1}\bigr)|_{U_1}\Bigr)_p=\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{dx_1}{x_2}\bigr)|_{U_2}\Bigr)_p
$$
right?

I can write $p=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Let $v\in T_p S^1$, then $v=-\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$.

Let's apply $\omega$ to $v$, then
$$
\Bigl(\bigl(-\frac{dx_2}{x_1}\bigr)|_{U_1}\Bigr)_p(v)=-\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=-1\\
\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{dx_1}{x_2}\bigr)|_{U_2}\Bigr)_p= -\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}=-1
$$
Is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in spirit this is OK. You should be specifying, however, that $U_i = \{x\in S^1: x_i\ne 0\}$. And your "then $v=$ ..." is not totally correct, as $v$ could be any scalar multiple of this vector.

An alternative approach (more amenable to generalization) is to observe that since $S^1$ is defined by the equation $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$, the $1$-form $$\frac 12 d(x_1^2+x_2^2) = x_1\,dx_1+x_2\,dx_2$$
is identically $0$ on $S^1$. It follows by simple algebra that $\dfrac{dx_1}{x_2}+ \dfrac{dx_2}{x_1} = 0$ wherever $x_1x_2\ne 0$, i.e., on $U_1\cap U_2$. It's better to learn to work with differential forms without always having to evaluate them on tangent vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much Ted! Your answer is really clear